# What is flops seen percentage?

Tags: poker-theory, programming

In a poker application I have to display flops seen percentage for each table. I understand flop is when 3 community cards are on the table. But what is 'flops seen'? I tried googling but could not understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply when a player does not fold before the flop. Folds pre-flop + flops seen = 100%. If a player is dealt 100 hands, and stays for the flop 32 of those hands, he saw 32% of the flops. I am assuming your talking about Holdem Omaha and other flop games. I would take it a little further and also do the same with the turn and the river.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So it is a player specific thing. Not for a table I guess. So if somebody asks me to find out 'flops seen %age' for a particular table, that question itself is wrong, right?

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta, it seems a perfectly valid metric.  It's just the fraction of deals where the flop is shown vs total deals (which would include some where a pot is awarded pre-flop).  I just don't know what the point is of table stats like that since it will vary based on the number of seats.  More flops will be seen with a full table than when a small number are playing.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Agreed. The flops seen % in a recent amount of time might be valuable (say, in the last 10-30 minutes) to indicate how loose the table is right now, compared to other tables.

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta I think that is a cool stat, gives you an ideal of how loose a player is.

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta you can definitely calculate it for a table just as well, but that'd be a different measurement